# Approach-Avoidance Conflicts

Tags: cognitive-psychology, motivation

I remember from my university days learning about approach-avoidance conflicts. Briefly, many situations are perceived as having an upside and a downside:

- If upside>downside, we are likely to be attracted to the situation.
- The closer we are to the situation (either in time or space), the stronger the upside and downside are perceived.
- The increase in the strength of a perceived downside is greater than that of the upside (the avoidance gradient is steeper than the approach gradient).
- This means that even though something may be more attractive now, the closer we are to the situation, the more the downside becomes prominent. At some point, upside

I also remember that the strengths of the gradients can be influenced. For example, alcohol has a tendency to weaken the perceived downside, so that a situation becomes more attractive for longer.

This would explain why people make some decisions which looked OK at the time but have a long term downside. It would also explain why alcohol can influence these decisions.

The question is: where can I read up more about this online?

Comment: Have you tried [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approach-avoidance_conflict)?  Articles on there often have links to other sites for further reading.  [Study.com](http://study.com/academy/lesson/approach-avoidance-conflict-definition-examples.html) has a definition and examples plus a video.

Comment: @Chris I hate to admit it, but Wikipedia was the first place I looked. The article was very light on and their links are to offline resources. Study.com requires registration, which I’m not inclined to do yet. Thanks

Comment: Sounds very similar to Tversky and Kahneman's work on expected value and utility or decision making under risk. Perhaps that may give you some more hits.